# JavaDoc for classes in an UberJAR?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-shade-plugin

We are building an UberJAR for plugin-development for an application. The developer only needs to depend on it to have all classes on their classpath. When done, only the plugin.jar ships since the target application has all the original dependencies on the classpath. Works like a charm.

The downside: the Uber-jar comes without JavaDoc, making it tedious to use. So we are looking for a way to provide a Uber-javadoc-jar. We looked at includes, but that didn' work.

```xml
<configuration>
  <artifactSet>
    <includes>
       <include>somePackage-javadoc.jar</include>
    </includes>
 </artifactSet>
</configuration>
```